# Adobe Illustrator Expand disabled

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i wanted to draw the same as in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04OAU4LFHSM

At 5:03 she uses the "expand" button but for me its disabled:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEvl0V7tmGM

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

windows 7 64
newest adobe illustrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using a different tool than the person in the tutorial is using. The tutorial is using the Pencil Tool (N). You're using the Paintbrush Tool (B).

You can still expand the paintbrush paths; Select all of the lines, go to Object -> Expand Appearance. Then go to Object -> Expand.

**What is the difference?**

The paintbrush has an effect applied to the path. When you expand the appearance of the paintbrush line, you're converting the appearance to an expanded path.

[image: expand appearance]

Comment: Ohh i should look more closely what the poeple do in the videos... thanks for the quick answer and explanation :)

Comment: Hi @SebastianSchoenberg, if this answers your question, please mark this as answered. Thank you.

Comment: I hope its now marked @ AndrewH